# Subset and join a data frame by matching on nested list in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr

I'm attempting to join two data frames, df and myData, according to elements in a column from each.  The column in df purposefully contains nested lists, and I would like to join if an element in the nested list matches an element of myData. I'd like to keep unmatched rows in df (left join).

Here is an example, first without nested lists in df.

```
df = data.frame(a=1:5)
df$x1= c("a", "b", "g", "a", "a")
str(df)

'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
$ a : int  1 2 3 4 5
$ x1: chr  "a" "b" "g" "a" ...

myData <- data.frame(x1=c("a", "g", "q"), x2= c("za", "zg", "zq"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Now, we can join on column x1:

```
#using a for loop
df$x2 <- NA
for(id in 1:nrow(myData)){
  df$x2[df$x1 %in% myData$x1[id]] <- myData$x2[id]
}
```

Or using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(a=1:5)
df$x1= c("a", "b", "g", "a", "a")
df %>%
  left_join(myData)
```

Now, consider df with nested lists.

```
l1 = list(letters[1:5])
l2 = list(letters[6:10])
df = data.frame(a=1:5)
df$x1= c("a", "b", "g", l1, l2)
```

Using a for loop fails to match on elements of a nested list, as we expect:

```
df$x2 <- NA
for(id in 1:nrow(myData)){
  df$x2[df$x1 %in% myData$x1[id]] <- myData$x2[id]
}
```

output:

```
df
  a            x1   x2
1 1             a   za
2 2             b <NA>
3 3             g   zg
4 4 a, b, c, d, e <NA>
5 5 f, g, h, i, j <NA>
```

Using dplyr:

```
df %>%
  left_join(myData)
```

throws an error:

```
Joining by: c("x1", "x2")
Error: cannot join on column 'x1'
```

I think the solution needs to unlist the nested lists, but haven't sorted out how to work the unlist function into the above strategies.

I've also tried the above with the data.table package. How to accomplish this with data.table is may be an additional question.  But, to the extent the data.table handles lists within data frames, I wanted to include it, as it may provide the best solution.

My actual data is about 100,000 rows, so the matching on lists with base R could be a performance annoyance (another reason to consider data.table ?)

Fwiw, the use of nested lists (and other structures) within data frames is something I would often do in Python, and it may be there is a better way to structure the data in the first place in R.

Thoughts?

Comment: This question calls out to me.  It says, "Use rapply. It may not be the fastest. It may not be the cleanest. It may not be the most comprehensible. But it will be the coolest."

Comment: Perhaps, it would be better to change your data to a long "data.frame" `DF = data.frame(a = rep(df$a, sapply(df$x1, length)), x1 = unlist(df$x1))` and operate on it. For what you're trying to do `merge` (`merge(DF, myData, by = "x1", all.x = T)`) is useful and if you really want the format you have you could use `aggregate` to condense your long data. Generally R can easily handle data with multiple categorical variables rather than nested lists for whatever the final goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might work.  When you're recursively operating on a list, it's a good idea to write a helper function to get the  values.

```
getMatch <- function(x, y) {
      z <- y[[2]][sort(match(x, y[[1]]))]
      z[!length(z)] <- NA
      z
}
> rapply(unname(df[-1]), getMatch, y = myData)
# [1] "za" NA   "zg" "za" "zg"
```

Or we can assign a new column using `within`

```
> within(df, { x2 <- sapply(df$x1, getMatch, y = myData) })
#  a            x1   x2
#1 1             a   za
#2 2             b <NA>
#3 3             g   zg
#4 4 a, b, c, d, e   za
#5 5 f, g, h, i, j   zg
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, as this solution doesn't match within the nested list (or nested vector)

Comment: For sure I'm missing something obvious, but what are we passing as x in this function getMatch(x) ?    Thanks for helpful suggestion about providing output.

Comment: @bassounds - I added an `rapply` answer. It doesn't seen to make much difference in my method though

Comment: Thanks, this was the best solution for my data, based on informal timing (much faster than for loops) and brevity of code.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible solution:

```
df$x2 <- NA
for(id in 1:nrow(df)) 
  {
  df$x2[id] <- ifelse(
    length(ff <- myData$x2[which(myData$x1 == intersect(df$x1[[id]], myData$x1))])==0, 
    NA, 
    ff)
  }

df
#  a            x1   x2
#1 1             a   za
#2 2             b <NA>
#3 3             g   zg
#4 4 a, b, c, d, e   za
#5 5 f, g, h, i, j   zg
```

There are some potential pitfalls with the above solution.  For example, if we change `l1` to have 2 possible matches (e.g. "a" and "g") :

```
l1 = list(letters[1:7])
df$x1= c("a", "b", "g", l1, l2)
```

This solution will not catch both matches, as is:

```
df$x2 <- NA
    for(id in 1:nrow(df)) 
      {
      df$x2[id] <- ifelse(
        length(ff <- myData$x2[which(myData$x1 == intersect(df$x1[[id]], myData$x1))])==0, 
        NA, 
        ff)
      }
Warning message:
In myData$x1 == intersect(df$x1[[id]], myData$x1) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

You could modify it to allow multiple matches, if needed.  Here are two different ways to do that, one uses `paste` and one uses `list` in the way you did in the problem.

```
df$x2 <- NA
    for(id in 1:nrow(df)) 
      {
      df$x2[id] <- 
        paste(if (length(ff <- myData$x2[which(myData$x1 %in% intersect(df$x1[[id]], myData$x1))])==0)
        NA else
        ff, collapse=", ")
      }


df$x2 <- NA
    for(id in 1:nrow(df)) 
      {
      df$x2[id] <- 
        list(if (length(ff <- myData$x2[which(myData$x1 %in% intersect(df$x1[[id]], myData$x1))])==0)
        NA else
        ff)
      }
```

Both will return the following, but the underlying structure will be different:

```
  a                  x1     x2
1 1                   a     za
2 2                   b     NA
3 3                   g     zg
4 4 a, b, c, d, e, f, g za, zg
5 5       f, g, h, i, j     zg
```

Comment: Thanks, this definitely works!  My actual data isn't likely to have multiple matches- but not impossible. And for a similar problem with multiple matches, the modifications would be crucial.  Many thanks for sorting out that possibility as well!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `data.table` option:

```
library(data.table)

# convert to data.table in place
setDT(myData)

# using Frank's extended example
l1 = list(letters[1:7])
l2 = list(letters[6:10])
dt = data.table(a=1:5, x1 = c("a", "b", "g", l1, l2))

# unlist the lists (and to be honest, that's how I would store the data,
# I think the column of lists is a bad idea), then set the keys, merge, and
# go back to columns of lists
setkey(dt[, unlist(x1), by = a], V1)[myData, x2 := i.x2][,
            list(x1 = list(V1), x2 = list(na.omit(x2))), keyby = a]
#   a           x1    x2
#1: 1            a    za
#2: 2            b      
#3: 3            g    zg
#4: 4 a,b,c,d,e,f, za,zg
#5: 5    f,g,h,i,j    zg
```

Comment: I seem to get an error: Error in setkeyv(ans, names(ans)[seq_along(byval)]) : 
  Item 2 of list is not a vector

Comment: @bassounds perhaps you have an older `data.table` version and smth has changed that I don't remember right now. I'm using version 1.9.3.

Comment: thanks, I was on 1.9.2 which is the latest CRAN version, but updated to 1.9.3 via github, and it works.